# allow SSH to bypass VPN on OSX mavericks, openvpn, pf

Tags: macos, networking, ssh, vpn, pf

My home computer connects to the internet through an OpenVPN connection. However, I would like to be able to connect to my home computer from outside over ssh. Ssh is set up and working, but when I connect to the vpn ssh is only accessible from inside my home network.

I figure what's going wrong is my router forwards incoming ssh connections to my mac, but then my mac replies over the vpn, so the connection from outside times out. I've got pf set up for a couple of other things, but I can't figure out how to let the ssh replies bypass the vpn using pf. I've come across other solutions that use ip tables, routing tables and rules, but I can't figure out how to set that up on mavericks.

I've been searching for this for a while now but I haven't found a working solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I'll add (part of) my current pf.conf for clarity, with added rules thanks to MariusMatutiae

```
#
# Macros
#
vpn_if = "tun0"
lan_if = "en0"
lan_gw = "x.x.x.x"
vpn_gw = "y.y.y.y"

#
# Ruleset
#
pass out on $lan_if route-to ($vpn_if $vpn_gw) from $vpn_if
pass out on $vpn_if route-to ($lan_if $lan_gw) from $lan_if
```

Update #2: Here are some of the rules I've tried to get this working (to no avail)

```
# Nat to make replies seem to come from my external ip address
nat on $lan_if -> $ext_ip

# Redirect incoming requests on the lan interface back to the lan interface
rdr pass on $lan_if from ! $lan to any -> ($lan_if)

# Make pf reply to lan interface 
pass in quick on $lan_if reply-to ($lan_if $lan_gw)
```

I'm really hoping someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis is correct: the initial contact is through your home router, the reply through the OpenVPN, your computer discards it for obvious security reasons.

What you are asking for is called `Policy-based-` or `Source-based-` routing. Basically, it means having two (or more) distinct routing tables, and switching between them according to some pre-defined rules. It exists in Linux, and exists in FreeBSD/OpenBSD thanks to PF, [see this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing). Since however PF does exists on Mac ([see here for instructions on how to set it up](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/15/using-pf-on-os-x-mountain-lion/)), I thought I could tell you how to do it in PF, even though, strictly speaking, I have done it in OpenBSD only (and Linux, of course).

Basically, the reference cited above tells you you have two choices for where to put the rules for your PF. Whichever you pick, add these rules to the file:

```
 ext_if1 = "ether"
 ext_if2 = "tun"
 ext_gw1 = "192.168.1.100"
 ext_gw2 = "10.0.0.3"
 pass out on $ext_if1 from $ext_if2 route-to ($ext_if2 $ext_gw2)
 pass out on $ext_if2 from $ext_if1 route-to ($ext_if1 $ext_gw1)
```

Here *ext_if1" is your ethernet connection via your router, and *192.168.1.100* its IP address, while *ext_if2* is your virtual interface (tun or tap, whatever), with IP address *10.0.0.3*. You should substitute appropriate addresses as per your needs.

BTW, this is lifted straight from the PF user manual, [here](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/pools.html#outgoing), except I simplified to accommodate your (simpler) request.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have tried to get this working in the past but hadn't been able to. The problem I'm running into now is that these rules generate a syntax error. I think this might be because apparently pf on osx uses older syntax. The rules seem to error out on the 'from' part, which seems essential to me to get it working. Perhaps some other rules are needed in the older syntax? I'm trying to find references, but no luck so far.

Comment: so, managed to get rid of the syntax error by moving the 'from' part to the end of the line, but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @zycho42 Judging from the manual page, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/pf.conf.5.html, there should not be any problem, see the example they make under the heading **Macros**. Are you sure you are doing the same thing?

Comment: I've updated my question to contain my pf.conf. It is not working however, ssh is not reachable from outside my home network - the connection times out. I've tried using nat and rdr as well, but so far nothing's worked.